# What exactly is the syntax error in this part of python code?

Tags: python

```
for k in range(m):
    sum_term += w[k] * (y_train[k] * math.log10(abs(np.longdouble(h[k])))) + ((1 - y_train[k]) * math.log10(abs(np.longdouble(1 -h[k]))))
```

Comment: What is the stacktrace? The error can be anything...

Comment: We have to see what error and trace you got in order to start understanding

Comment: Also, this is almost unreadable in one line, separate it to multiple steps and it will help you figure out which one of them fails

Comment: I don't get a `SyntaxError`. Maybe you forgot to close the parenthesis somewhere above these lines?

Comment: there is an extra close parenthesis at the end other than that it should work

Comment: @user93 I don't see one, and the code compiles without a `SyntaxError`, so...

Comment: we are going to need more information, as it stands no one can find your syntax error and we cannot run your code

Answer (score 0):

There is no `SyntexError` and code compiles without error. A value error can occur if you do `log` of a negative number.